# How to calculate containers' cpu usage in kubernetes with prometheus as monitoring?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I want to calculate the cpu usage of all pods in a kubernetes cluster. I found two metrics in prometheus may be useful:

```
container_cpu_usage_seconds_total: Cumulative cpu time consumed per cpu in seconds.
process_cpu_seconds_total: Total user and system CPU time spent in seconds.

Cpu Usage of all pods = increment per second of sum(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"})/increment per second of sum(process_cpu_seconds_total)
```

However, I found every second's increment of `container_cpu_usage{id="/"}` larger than the increment of `sum(process_cpu_seconds_total)`. So the usage may be larger than 1...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This I'm using to get CPU usage at cluster level:

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100
```

I also track the CPU usage for each pod.

```
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)
```

I have a complete kubernetes-prometheus solution on GitHub, maybe can help you with more metrics: https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I confirm whether `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100
 ` represents a percentage of cpu usage, or simply a number of core that the container consume?

Comment: I am getting some weird results with `sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m])) / sum (machine_cpu_cores) * 100` to all my containers I get a number between 0 and 1, but for nginx-ingress-controller and fluentd-gcp I get from 0 to 3...

Comment: Which metric did you use to calculate the current number of used cores?

Comment: @Camil I m looking for more metrics in your github but I do not find anyone... where are them ?

Comment: at the cluster level, why do you use container metrics? wouldn't it be better to use the cpu metrics exposed by node exporter?

Answer (score 12):

The following query returns per-container average number of CPUs used during the last 5 minutes:

```
rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!~"POD|"}[5m])
```

The lookbehind window in square brackets (`5m` in the case above) can be changed to the needed value. See possible time duration values [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).

The `container!~"POD|"` filter removes metrics related to cgroups hierarchy (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328) for more details) and metrics for e.g. `pause` containers (see [these docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683403/what-is-the-container-pod-label-in-prometheus-and-why-do-most-examples-exclude)).

Since each `pod` can contain multiple containers, then the following query can be used for returning per-pod average number of CPUs used during the last 5 minutes:

```
sum(
  rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!~"POD|"}[5m])
) by (namespace,pod)
```

Comment: Regarding "per-pod average number of CPUs", I see only sum() where is the average here?

Comment: The pod may contain multiple containers. Each container may use some CPU. So you need to use sum() across all the pod's containers in order to get CPU usage of the pod. As for the `average` word - it is related to the `rate(m[d])` - it returns the *average* per-second increase rate for `m` metric over the lookbehind window `d` - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate

Comment: Thanks a lot. A few more cases 1. if my container (say lookup service) runs in different pods, then how do I know avg CPU usage of my service 2. To tell %of use; do I need manually calculate and divide the above value with (no of containers * CPU allocated) in my deployment YAML? These answers really help me and others.

Comment: this saved my month. I have wondering why values were not matching. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I created my own prometheus exporter (https://github.com/google-cloud-tools/kube-eagle), primarily to get a better overview of my resource utilization on a per node basis. But it also offers a more intuitive way monitoring your CPU and RAM resources. The query to get the cluster wide CPU usage would look like this:

```
sum(eagle_pod_container_resource_usage_cpu_cores)
```

But you can also easily get the CPU usage by namespace, node or nodepool.

Comment: this answer is very underrated / great tool. A big problem with prometheus is a lack of standardization. kubernetes resource limits and requests are based on milli cpu It doesn't make sense that Prometheus Metrics don't also standardize on Milli CPU, I get that Prometheus doesn't just run on Kubernetes, but can't you export both metric styles side by side or even do [classic cpu % used] * 100 / 1000 to do a logical conversion to milli CPUs for the sake of standardization?

Answer (score 5):

**Metric definition**

- `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` - CPU usage time in seconds of a specific container, as the name suggests. A rate on top of this will show how many CPU seconds a container uses per second.
- `container_spec_cpu_period` - Denotes the period in which container CPU utilization is tracked. I understood this as the duration of a CPU "cycle". Typically `100000` microseconds for docker containers.
- `container_spec_cpu_quota` - How much CPU time your container has for each cpu_period in microseconds—results from multiplying a "CPU unit" by the `container_spec_cpu_period`. **You only have it if you define a limit for your container**.

`container_spec_cpu_quota / container_spec_cpu_period` will tell you how many CPU seconds you have in each second, then the CPU usage of the container could be `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total /(container_spec_cpu_quota / container_spec_cpu_period)`.

---

One sample

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container_name!="POD"}[5m])) by (pod_name, container_name)
/sum(container_spec_cpu_quota{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container_name!="POD"}
  /container_spec_cpu_period{name!~".*prometheus.*", image!="", container_name!="POD"}) by (pod_name, container_name)
```

---

Source:

[Average CPU % usage per container](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2026)

Comment: This does not appear to work very well in all cases, it shows negative numbers which should not exist

Comment: @rofls, Do you define a limit for your container?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use below query as well:

```
avg (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/"}[1m]))
```