# prometheus query is showing almost twice value for CPU usage of pod as compared to kubectl top command

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

Prometheus query that I am running :

`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod!=""}[5m])) by (pod)`

this gets me around 450m.

And kubectl top for that particular pod is 225m.

Am I missing something?

Prometheus query is always showing 2x usage.

Comment: There is an entry that shows combined CPU usage for the whole pod, your `sum()` combines it with per-container measures. Same as with memory usage in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281327/why-container-memory-usage-is-doubled-in-cadvisor-metrics/69282328#69282328

Answer (score 0):

Can you check trying as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40391872/2310790 ?
sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)

The kubectl top command returns current CPU and memory usage for a cluster's pods or nodes, or for a particular pod or node if specified. And you had mentioned 5m rate. So i am suspicious if the rates impact your comparison.

Comment: This works : 


sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)

This gives 2x values : 

sum (rate (container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_name!="POD",pod!=""}[1m])) by (pod_name)

Very strange.

Comment: I have never come across this container_name, pod combination. But I am glad that the solution works for you..!

Comment: Great, but why are the metrics duplicated, with and without an image tag?